# Make keypress inline in html element to catch enter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

If I have html element like this

```
<input type = "text" onkeypress="if(this.keyCode == 13){alert()}" />
```

Not work,
Please advice

Comment: `event.keyCode`, Use `event` instead of `this`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can try like this

```html
<input type = "text" onkeypress="javascript: if(event.keyCode == 13) alert();" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Replace `this.keyCode` with `event.keyCode`

```html
<input type = "text" onkeypress="if(event.keyCode == 13){alert('you press enter')}" />
```

Answer (score 2):

The event.which property normalizes **event.keyCode** and **event.charCode**. It is recommended to watch event.which for keyboard key input. And: In a keypress event, the Unicode value of the key pressed is stored in either the keyCode or charCode property, never both.

```js
function catchEnter(event) {
  if(event.keyCode === 13) {
       alert('catch enter');
  }
}
```

```html
<input type = "text" onkeypress="catchEnter(event)" />
```

Answer (score 0):

**Minimal code of function:**

```html
<input type ="text" onkeypress="if(event.keyCode == 13) alert('you press enter')"/>
```

You are not able to submit 1 more action, you do not need `{ }`.

Answer (score -2):

You need just only to use this boot of code without Code :

Try it and keep me updated with the result hope this help you :D